# Microsoft Word Printing on command line

Tags: command-line, microsoft-word, printing

As you know we can automatically send a docx file to printer via MS Office Word command line orders:

```
"WINWORD.EXE" /q /n "doc.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit
```

Can we also set the printing amount/count on the command line? Is there any to do it?

Comment: "Is there any to do it?" Yes, write the appropriate macro.

Comment: I'm developing Electron JS application. I can not include macro